# Native Code Typescript Compiler

Tags: javascript, c++, c, node.js, typescript

I really like Typescript as a sane alternative to Javascript, but I hate that it pulls node.js as a dependancy. To make matters worse, there only appears to be one compiler for the language in existence, and it's self-hosted. Isn't there any standalone `tsc` executable?

To be clear, I'm not looking to *execute* anything, I just want a compiler that takes in a list of typescript source files and produces one or more javascript object files.

Comment: What is the problem with having Node.js as a dependency? After all, it is just a development dependency so why does it matter?

Comment: @str Because I hate it. Does it matter why? A binary would be smaller, faster, and more to my liking.

Comment: The official [TypeScript dev tools](http://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html#download-links) have dependencies. If you don't like those (either tools or dependencies), you are free to download the [language specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md) and write your own compiler, that doesn't have any dependencies. With that out of the way, this question doesn't appear to be a practical programming issue. It is, as such, off-topic for SO.

Comment: I mean, it's a question about programming...

Answer (score 1):

use [typescript tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790) developed by microsoft for visual studio . when you will install these tools it will automatically install dependency so you don't have freak out with nodejs :)

Comment: Nah, I'm a Linux guy. And anyway, my issue is that I don't want node.js to touch my machine, not that I don't want to interface with it. Thanks though!

Comment: The link in this answer is broken now.